# Cronômetro - Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

Fiz um cronometro(melhor dizendo: um temporizador) que deve ser executado quando um certo botão for clicado. Eu consegui fazer o temporizador, só que não consigo encerra-lo. Depois de chamado ele fica cronometrando "pra sempre" rs.

Gostaria que me ajudassem.
Código:

```
package controller;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import view.View;

/**
 *
 * @author Higor
 */
public class Cronometro {

    private View view;
    private Timer timer;
    private ActionListener action;
    private int minutos;
    private int segundos;

    public Cronometro(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void go(boolean cond) {
        if (cond == true) {
            action = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    view.getLbCronometro().setText("0" + minutos + " : " + ++segundos + "");
                    if (segundos == 59) {
                        segundos = 0;
                        minutos = 1;
                    }
                }
            };
            timer = new Timer(1000, action);
            timer.start();
        } else {
            view.getLbCronometro().setText("Resultado.");
            timer.stop();
            /**
             * Gera erro aqui, quando eu chamo a função go com parâmetro false.
             * Que seria para encerrar o temporizador.
             */
        }
    }
}
```

O timer stop gera esse erro:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.Cronometro.go(Cronometro.java:39)
    at controller.Controller$Temporizador$Tempo.run(Controller.java:356)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

E o cronometro continua...

A minha intenção era fazer o cronometro parar quando fizesse dois minutos. E então o label mudaria para "Resultado", porque eu chamaria chamaria a função 'go' passando como parâmetro false.
Obrigado aos que ajudarem.

Comment: O que `view.getLbCronometro` retorna? Qual é a linha 39 do seu código? Se, como eu estou pensando, é a linha onde você faz `setText("Resultado")`, então com certeza esse método está retornando `null`.

Comment: view : classe da interface visual
getLbCronometro: encapsulamento do JLabel lbCronometro, e ele retorta o lbCronometro.  A linha 39 é o timer.stop.

Comment: Hm, me enganei então... Nesse caso, você tem certeza que está chamando o método no mesmo `Cronometro` que você iniciou antes? (i.e. não está criando uma outra instância) Porque se na linha 39 o `timer` é nulo, então isso só pode significar que a primeira parte do código (em que `cond` é `true`) não executou [para essa instância].

Comment: Não não estou instanciando. Mais eu percebi que eu estava  instanciando o timer somente dentro do if, e consequentemente não pegaria no else, originando o NullPointerException. Arrumei esse probleminha, mas mesmo assim. O cronometro não para, ele vai direto.

Comment: Se você puder postar o resto do código para que ele possa ser compilado e testado, seria ótimo! (Como é um `NullPointerException`, você provavelmente vai descobrir o seu erro reduzindo o código para que ele caiba aqui... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Você deve colocar a condição para o cronometro parar dentro da action
Ex:

```
timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {


        if (/* Cronometro = 2 Minutos */) {
            timer.stop();
            //...Update the GUI...
        }
    }    
});
```